# How to repeat program after running the whole program in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, program-entry-point, repeat

I wrote a short program comparing two integers and providing an appropriate answer at the end. I want the program to repeat itself in case integer was not written in 'userint'.

Core program:

```
from random import randint
rn = randint(0,5)
print("The randomly generated integer is:",rn)
userint= input("Enter an integer:")

try:
    if userint == rn:
        print("Numbers are equal!")
    elif userint > rn:
        print(userint)
    else:
        print(rn)
except:
    print("You have not entered an integer!")

if input("Do you want to repeat(y/n)").lower()== "  N":
    break
```

Here is what I have tried using:

```
while True:
    from random import randint
    rn = randint(0,5)
    print("The randomly generated integer is:",rn)
    userint= input("Enter an integer:")

    try:
        if userint == rn:
            print("Numbers are equal!")
        elif userint > rn:
            print(userint)
        else:
            print(rn)
    except:
        print("You have not entered an integer!")

    if input("Do you want to repeat(y/n)").lower()== "  N":
        break
```

I have also tried another method of repeating the program as:

```
def main():

    from random import randint
    rn = randint(0,5)
    print("The randomly generated integer is:",rn)
    userint= input("Enter an integer:")

    try:
        if userint == rn:
            print("Numbers are equal!")
        elif userint > rn:
            print(userint)
        else:
            print(rn)
    except:
        print("You have not entered an integer!")

    restart = input("Do you want to start again?").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        exit()
main()
```

In both cases, program asks a user to input the value. Than, despite the value it runs the restart part of the program without conduction actual comparison of the values.

Could someone guide me on how to fix the program and allow it to compare values and if user inputs not an integer print("You have not entered an integer!"), ask "Do you want to start again?", and run the program again?

Comment: You're making the input lowercase and comparing it to an uppercase string.

Comment: there was never an int comparison in your code.  You're comparing  string to int; which surely will cause except block to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isnumeric to check whether the input is integer or not.

```
def main():

    from random import randint
    rn = randint(0,5)
    print("The randomly generated integer is:",rn)
    userint= input("Enter an integer:")
    if userint.isnumeric():
        userint=int(userint)
    try:
        if userint == rn:
            print("Numbers are equal!")
        elif userint > rn:
            print(userint)
        else:
            print(rn)
    except:
        print("You have not entered an integer!")

    restart = input("Do you want to start again?").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        exit()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your try/except block. The try block will not run any lines of code enclosed in that block if any of those lines fail. In your case, you have a failing line due to your userint variable being a string while rn is an int. In the context of your example, this can be fixed simply adding the following line to the top of the try block:

```
try:
    userint = int( userint )
    ...
except:
    ...
```

If it's not possible to convert userint to a string, the try block will fail and you'll print your error message instead.